# Scroll to the dropped object when it's released outside of the current view of a GEF editor

Tags: drag-and-drop, autoscroll, eclipse-gef

I have a GEF editor with draggable figures. I have overriden the createChangeConstraintCommand of the main EditPart's XYLayoutEditPolicy.
This allows me to easily move (drag and drop) the figures.

The problem is, that if I drag one of them outside of the current view, although the scroll appears and the figure is moved, the view does not automatically scrolls to the dropped object.

Any idea how to implement this "auto-scroll" functionality? (It would be even nicer to have the "selected" (dragged/dropped) figure always visible in the view.)

Answer (score 0):

Given the editpart object that has been dropped, you should use `EditPartViewer#reveal(EditPart)` method. Do this for example:

```
editpart.getViewer().reveal(editpart)
```

Comment: I called the reveal function asynchronously (!) from the editpart's notifyChanged method. This allows me to have the screen scrolled when the object is dropped, after the changeconstraint command has been executed. But I still have no success with the dragging part... the drag&drop is controlled by the editpolicy. In this case, where should I call the reveal method from?

Comment: In other words you'd like to show the editpart being dragged when it's dragged outside the viewport? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: Use org.eclipse.draw2d.FigureCanvas.scrollSmoothTo(int x, int y). You'd need the x and y in appropriate coordinate system for that. See the implementation of org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.ScrollingGraphicalViewer.reveal(EditPart part) to understand how coordinates translation are performed

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I've overriden the createChangeConstraintCommand method in XYLayoutEditPolicy with: Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {@Override public void run() {int x = request.getTransformedRectangle((Rectangle) constraint).x;
int y = request.getTransformedRectangle((Rectangle) constraint).y;
((FigureCanvas) child.getViewer().getControl()).scrollSmoothTo(x, y); }}); This successfully allows the editpart to be shown when it is dragged, but the mouse doesn't stay over the figure (it's shifted), which is very annoying...